# if IE9 has no progress bar, what show that it's working so I don't click "post" again

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I has a slow connection so, from 1st time I used IE9, I'm often click "Post" button >1 times (or some stuff like that, my company work with a web app). I've GOOGLED and known that IE9 has no progress bar, and no plugins will help. So please tell me some trick on the IE9 GUI to know it's working or not!
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can tell whether or not a webpage is loading by looking at the tab - if it's still loading, there should be a circular animated icon shown there, instead of the website's own icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the progress back in IE9. Google "Xinify statusbar progress for internet explorer 9" and you will find a simple plugin that works well!

Comment: Hi Richard, welcome to SuperUser! All your posts are signed with your username and current reputation, so we generally discourage putting a signature in the answer as well. Also, if you could provide a link to the plugin you are referring to, it would make your answer much more useful. Is [this](http://www.xinify.com/StatusBar-Progress-For-Internet-Explorer-9-XSBP-2012-1USR-VS1.htm) what you're referring to? Thank you!